# Add @Override annotation automatically on save in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, editor

I'm currently in the process of switching from Eclipse to IntelliJ and cannot get a couple of features to work that I'm familiar with from Eclipse.

My current issue:

I have a two classes, `A` and `B`:

```java
public interface A {
}

public class B implements A {

  public void foo() {
  }

}
```

Now let's add the method `foo` to the interface `A`:

```java
public interface A {
  void foo();
}
```

In Eclipse, after making this change, when I open class `B`, make any kind of change **and then save the file** Eclipse will automatically add the `@Override` annotation to method `foo` in class `B`, so that it looks like this:

```java
public class B implements A {

  @Override
  public void foo() {
  }

}
```

I cannot get IntelliJ to replicate that behaviour. I adjust interface `A`, I go to class `B`, make some change but IntelliJ **doesn't automatically add the `@Override` annotation on save**.

Am I missing a configuration setting?

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ doesn't add `@Override` annotation automatically. I don't think it's possible to achieve without some 3rd-party plugin, so you cannot replicate this behaviour.

## *Missing @Override annotation* inspection

However, there is an "inspection" (see [list](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/list-of-java-inspections.html)), called *Missing @Override annotation*. You can search for this in the Settings window. This inspection:

> Reports methods overriding superclass methods but are not annotated with @java.lang.Override.

You can increase severity of it to "Error" and it will highlight all the methods with missing annotation. You will be able to quick-fix them by hitting <kbd>alt/option</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: You can enable "Actions on Save" in the settings and run enabled code cleanup inspections on save. The "Missing @Override annotation" is a code cleanup inspection, so it can be used in this way.

Comment: where is this to find?

Comment: @TonyB It's under Settings > Editor > Inspections > Java > Inheritance issues

Comment: or use this plugin https://github.com/wanghuan9/intellij-plugin-save-action-tool